# change div css style if browser safari

Tags: css, html, safari

I have the following div:

```
<div id="views" style="margin-top:34px; margin-left:35px;">

// code...

</div>
```

this works perfect for me in all explorers but in safari in order to work perfect I need to set margin-top: -40 px; Any idea which is the easiest way to do this? I mean to make is select browser and if safari to apply margin-top: -40 px;

Comment: Try -webkit-margin-before: -40px but it may be overwritten by your margin-top:34px;

Comment: @Clayton this will work in chrome as well, and might cause problems..

Comment: If you could post the corresponding `html` and `css` it'll be easier to check what's the problem and fix it. it's most likely that you won't be needing browser specific fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take out your inline styles.
2. Detect the browser by JavaScript,
   add a class of `.safari` to the `body` tag if Safari is detected, then have your general
   and Safari specific styles like this:

CSS:

```
#views {
    margin-top:34px;
    margin-left:35px;
}

.safari #views {
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left:35px;
}
```

Safari styles will be applied to Safari due to higher [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set specific vendor prefixes (although chrome and safari are both webkit)
this way you could set different styles for different browsers.

[Vender Specific Prefix](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/)

Or the much more difficult way... detecting the browser and assigning CSS

[Browser Detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

You should post some code though, I feel this problem your having could be avoided in a much more graceful manner.